# How to set two layouts in one ListView

Tags: android, listview, layout

I want to make two layouts in a listview like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: have you even tried anything? [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_inflating) can be useful to you

Comment: there is just one layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Listview allows you to define the concept of ViewType, allowing you to inflate different layouts depending of the object's "type" you define, in your example it would be with or without picture.

see http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296 for a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

The "second" layout is NOT a second layout, it's just a child view of the first layout. Its default visibility state is hidden, and when you want to show it( according to row index etc..) just do:

```
secondLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a lote work going on first go to learn Custom ListView Adapter here is some link

يوجد هناك كثير من العمل يجب القياب به اولا اذهب و تعلم`Custom ListView Adapter`

1-http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

2-http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-listview

3-http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429